# Como posso treinar uma rede neural com partidas anteriores?

Tags: inteligência-artificial, redes-neurais

Suponhamos que eu queira ensinar uma rede neural a jogar xadrez. Realizei o método de aprendizado por reforço. Já vi casos em que estas redes aprendem com exemplos de partidas, mas como isso pode ser feito?